# Mathematical statement problem

Tags: align

I want to write a mathematical statement which also has to be numbered. For example :

> The function f is bounded (1.1)

However, the `align` environment does not work. Any hints?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I have a hint: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). For a quick advice: Look into `amsmath` documentation for the command `\text`.

Comment: What number should it be given? Will it share the numbering with equations? With theorems? Where should the number be placed?

Comment: Could you provide an minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem? I don't quite understand, why `align` won't work and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Share numberings with equations. The above number is an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:whatever}
\text{The function $f$ is bounded}
\end{equation}
```

The text will be centered and numbered. The label allows you to refer to the line later with `\ref{eq:whatever}`.

(Edited to incorporate commenters' changes.)

Comment: Ok, this is what i needed. Thanks @Ethan Bolker.

Comment: you might also consider using `\eqref` if you want the xref to be enclosed automatically in (always upright) parentheses.